# How to evaluate combinators productions right to left in Scala

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I have a simple parser which recognizes programs with the following form `print <expression> where <declarations>`, an example of complete program is

```
print x+y+z+1+x+-3 where x = 25, y = 1, z = -7
```

I've written the following evaluator for it

```scala
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

class DeskParserCombinators() extends JavaTokenParsers {
    var memory : Map[String, Int] = Map()

    def desk = "print" ~> expression ~ ("where" ~> variable_inizialization) ^^ {case e ~ d => (e, memory)}
    def expression = repsep(element, "+") ^^ {elements => elements.foldLeft(0){_+_}}
    def element = variable | value
    def variable_inizialization = repsep(declaration, ",")
    def declaration = """[a-z]""".r ~ ("=" ~> value) ^^ {case n ~ v => memory = memory + (n -> v)}
    def variable = """[a-z]""".r ^^ {(name: String) =>
        if(!memory.contains(name))
            throw new Exception("variable not declared " + name)
        memory(name)
    }
    def value = wholeNumber ^^ {v => v.toInt}
}

// === main ===
val parser = new DeskParserCombinators()
parser.parseAll(parser.desk, program) match {
    case parser.Success((result, memory), _) =>
        println(result)
        println(memory)
    case x => print(x.toString)
}
```

The program compiles, but as it is written in the case of the first `desk` rule the `expression` part is evaluated before the variable declaration part and therefore every execution that contains variables in the first part raises the defined exception

Is there a way to have the right-hand side evaluate first and only then evaluate the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By keeping the same structure of your definitions, you can prevent `expression` from being evaluated early by making its result a function, that way you can decide when to evaluate it:

```scala
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

class DeskParserCombinators() extends JavaTokenParsers {
    var memory : Map[String, Int] = Map()

    def desk = "print" ~> expression ~ ("where" ~> variable_inizialization) ^^ {case e ~ d => (e(), memory)}
    def expression = repsep(element, "+") ^^ {elements =>
        elements.foldLeft(() => 0)((f1, f2) => () => f1() + f2())  
    }
    def element = variable | value
    def variable_inizialization = repsep(declaration, ",")
    def declaration = """[a-z]""".r ~ ("=" ~> value) ^^ {case n ~ v => memory = memory + (n -> v())}
    def variable = """[a-z]""".r ^^ {(name: String) =>
        () => {
            if(!memory.contains(name))
                throw new Exception("variable not declared " + name)
            memory(name)
        }
    }
    def value = wholeNumber ^^ {v => () => {v.toInt}}
}
```

Of course, other definitions must also be changed to make them return functions
There is probably a better solution, but this doesn't alter the structure of the grammar you defined

Comment: I can't find where the expression is evaluated, but it works... thanks for the reply

Comment: The expression is evaluated within the `desk` rule match, as you can see it says `e()`, by the time you get to this point the parsing has already been completed and the variables stored

Comment: Oh, I see it tanks